# Синхронизация нитей

Tags: потоки-данных, многопоточность

Есть 3 нити. Как синхронизировать их так, чтобы первая нить постоянно формировала очередь из 5 элементов и передавала во вторую нить. Вторая нить, приняв элемент перезаписывала их во второй массив, передав его 3 нити, которая запишет результирующий массив в файл. Синхронизировать используя семафоры.

Comment: @isap, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к предложениям выполнить работу.

Comment: Вот вы пишете, что у вас есть приложение, которое работает в три потока. Это уже плохо, так как если все эти потоки будут работать одновременно( даже если они будут синхронизированы между собой ), то это может просто не ускорить работу программы, т.к количество ядер процессора может быть меньше количества потоков.

Comment: @asen, многопоточность используется не только для ускорения вычислений.

Comment: Это понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Ну так делаете три нити и две очереди. У каждой очереди по семафору, чтобы две нити не ломанулись одновременно.

Когда хотите что-то записать или прочитать в/из очереди — поднимаете семафор, закончили — опускаете. Подсматривать, есть ли в очереди элементы, можно без блокировок — главное учитывать, что за время между тем, как подсмотрели, и тем, как подняли семафор, все могло поменяться. Но, учитывая, что у каждой очереди сообщений только один источник и один потребитель, тут беспокоиться не о чем — если было сообщение, то его кроме нас забирать некому.

Вот, в общем-то, и вся синхронизация. Дальше все зависит от того какой у Вас язык, какие нити и какие очереди.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку очереди фиксированного размера (первая на 5, вторая ??? элементов) процесс синхронизации операций (конкретно: поместить в очередь, если на полна; взять из очереди, если не пуста) упростится, если использовать для каждой очереди 3 семафора.

Первый - empty (инициализируем количеством доступного места в очереди, поставщик делает wait на него, потребитель post)

Второй - full (инициализируем нулем, потребитель wait, поставщик post)

Третий - sync (инициализируем единицей, и потребитель и поставщик делают wait перед изменением структуры данных очереди и post по завершении изменения очереди)

Если неясно, могу дополнить ответ кодом для C posix threads.